# ProAspCompLib.dll - what is this for?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

Trying to dissect a very badly written ASP.NET app. Can someone tell me what this assembly (ProAspCompLib.dll) is used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after some brief google-fu, my best guess is a code library associated with a (Chinese) programming book. If this is the case you may be able to find the original/translated English version. http://book.csdn.net/bookfiles/172/1001727754.shtml .

Instead of trying to track this book down, a better option would be to examine the library using the free [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).